# Excel VBA Replace endless case statements with better alternative

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am populating a combobox with a row in the worksheet, then when picking that item in the combobox i want it to hide or unhide that row. It works with my case statements, but how can i do this simpler because there are far too many case statements to add when the range is F:BO?

```
 Dim pick1 As String
    pick1 = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

Application.Columns("F:BO").Select
Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

         Select Case pick1
            Case Sheets(1).Range("F6").Value
                Application.Columns("F").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case Sheets(1).Range("G6").Value
                Application.Columns("G").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case Sheets(1).Range("H6").Value
                Application.Columns("H").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case Sheets(1).Range("I6").Value
                Application.Columns("I").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Case Sheets(1).Range("J6").Value
                Application.Columns("J").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

            Case Else
                Application.Columns("F:BO").Select
                Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

       End Select
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the worksheet function MATCH to find the correct column and then use the resulting column number to unhide.

Also a note, avoid the use of `.Select` it is rarely needed and only slows down the code:

```
Dim pick1 As String
Dim ColNum As Long
ColNum = 0

pick1 = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet
    .Columns("F:BO").Hidden = True
    On Error Resume Next
        ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(pick1, .Range("6:6"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ColNum = 0 Then
        .Columns("F:BO").Hidden = False
    Else
        .Columns(ColNum).Hidden = False
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you a flexible solution which works on DropDown's vale.
Simply make one dropdown box any where like for example in B3 and add two values to it Yes & No. Then use the below written code.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then

        Application.Columns("F:BO").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Elseif Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "No" Then

        Application.Columns("F:BO").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End If

End Sub
```

**NB:** Alternatively, you can use Checkbox to Hide/Unhide Columns or through the InputBox you can use different columns to Hide/Unhide.

*Hope this help you.*